# How to put an add in for word 2013 using manifest.xml

Tags: ms-word, add-in, office-js

I have created an add in for word 2013 task pane

now I want to to check whether it is working or not

where and how should i keep the manifest.xml file so has to see whether the add in is working properly or not.

PS:  I do not want to use office online it should be through the word in the desktop.

so I would go to File> options > add ins > manage add ins > xml schema > add > (I would add the manifest.xsd to it )

after this also I am not able to view the add in in the my - apps tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

<!-- See https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples for documentation-->

<!-- BeginBasicSettings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided -->

<!--IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in. If you clone this manifest ensure that you change this id to your own GUID -->
  <Id>e504fb41-a92a-4526-b101-542f357b7acb</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
   <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various placed of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Add-in Commands Sample" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Sample that illustrates add-in commands basic control types and actions" />
   <!--Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/oZFS95h.png" />

  <!--BeginTaskpaneMode integration. Office 2013 and any client that doesn't understand commands will use this section.
    This section will also be used if there are no VersionOverrides -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
   <!--EndTaskpaneMode integration -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <!--BeginAddinCommandsMode integration-->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">   
    <Hosts>
      <!--Each host can have a different set of commands. Cool huh!? -->
      <!-- Workbook=Excel Document=Word Presentation=PowerPoint -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest -->
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

           <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in. 
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
                        <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
                        <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>

                        <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
                        <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>

                        <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL. 
                            resid points to a Url resource -->
                        <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
                    </GetStarted>

            <!--Function file is an html page that includes the javascript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called. 
            Think of the FunctionFile as the "code behind" ExecuteFunction-->
          <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" />

          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!--Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab -->
            <!-- Documentation includes all the IDs currently tested to work -->
            <CustomTab id="Contoso.Tab1">
                <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name-->
              <Group id="Contoso.Tab1.Group1">
                 <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel" />
                <Icon>
                <!-- Sample Todo: Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized -->
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                </Icon>

                <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.FunctionButton">
                <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                     <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                  <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                    <FunctionName>writeText</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>Button2Id1</TaskpaneId>
                     <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane1.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
            <!-- Menu example -->
            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="Contoso.Menu">
              <Label resid="Contoso.Dropdown.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="Contoso.Dropdown.Label" />
                <Description resid="Contoso.Dropdown.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="Contoso.Menu.Item1">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.Item1.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.Item1.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.Item1.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>MyTaskPaneID1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane1.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Item>

                <Item id="Contoso.Menu.Item2">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.Item2.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.Item2.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.Item2.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>MyTaskPaneID2</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane2.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Item>

              </Items>
            </Control>

              </Group>

              <!-- Label of your tab -->
              <!-- If validating with XSD it needs to be at the end, we might change this before release -->
              <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.TabLabel" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/FkSShX9.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/qDujiX0.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/FunctionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane1.Url" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane2.Url" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane2.html" />
         <!--LearnMore URL currently not used -->
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/GetStarted.html">
        </bt:Url>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Execute Function" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Dropdown.Label" DefaultValue="Dropdown" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item1.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane 1" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item2.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane 2" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Test Group" />
         <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.TabLabel" DefaultValue="Test Tab" />
         <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Simple add-in was succesfully loaded">
          <bt:Override Locale="ja-jp" Value="JA-JP Get Started Title" />
        </bt:String>      
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Execute Function" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Dropdown.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Options on this Menu" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item1.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Taskpane1" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item2.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Taskpane2" />
          <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Get going by opening TEST TAB on the Ribbon">
          <bt:Override Locale="ja-jp" Value="JA-JP Get Started Title" />
        </bt:String>  
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

here is the manifest.xml  file

Comment: Always mention the technologies used. In your case from the code it is likely that you mean to ask about OfficeJS, the new App Model where the question was tagged XML and VSTO (the 'old' COM Object Model Apps). Be as verbose as you can be with what you tried, how you did that and what the result (errors, messages, output, etc.) was.

Comment: See information on sideloading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

Answer (score 0):

To see if the add-in is working properly ,you would need to sideload it. Make sure your id is specified and change it to a unique GUID from the default in the manifest.xml. You can use [office-toolbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-toolbox) to sideload it.

```
 office-toolbox sideload -m manifest.xml -a word
```

This works for both windows and macOS. Following that you need to go to **insert ->Add-ins -> My add-ins ->**

[image]

PS: You can either use only office tab or custom tab in the manifest xml not both.